# Make Python's Interactive Interpreter Class Print Evaluated Expressions

Tags: python

When you use the Python Interactive Interpreter, you can enter an expression, say `1+1` and it'll print the value. If you write `1+1` in a script, it will not print anything, which makes perfect sense.

However, when you create a subclass of `code.InteractiveInterpreter`, then pass `1+1` into it, using the `runcode` method, it will not print `2`, which makes less sense.

Does anyone know of a **clean** way to make an `InteractiveInterpreter` instance print the value of expressions?

Note: This needs to be pretty robust as the application provides a shell to users, and we all know what they're like.

Cheers

*P.S. This is for a Python3 application, but a better Python2 solution will get the check.*

Comment: seems like you just want `runsource` instead of `runcode`?

Comment: Just tested this a bit, and it only works if the input is a single Python statement. The user can enter a block with multiple statements, so this isn't going to work as is. Do you have any ideas on fixing that issue?

Comment: It also, strangely, stops other things being printed. Doing `if True: print(1)` doesn't print anything :/

Comment: Not really answer to your question but [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython) is what you should look at for a robust, well-maintained python interactive shell, it's quite easy to embed it in your apps.

Comment: I learnt to program in IPython, and use it everyday, but it doesn't do what I need. The Notebook is too task specific (literate scientific and numerical work), and I need to integrate the browser, not just run inside it. Also, IPython doesn't run on Android, and I use that everyday too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that what [`code.InteractiveConsole`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/code.html#interactive-console-objects) is for?

```
>>> import code
>>> console = code.InteractiveConsole()
>>> r = console.push('1+1')
2
>>> r = console.push('x = 4 + 1')
>>> r = console.push('x + 10')
15

>>> r = console.push('def test(n):')
>>> r = console.push('  return n + 5')
>>> r = console.push('')
>>> r = console.push('test(10)')
15
```

Or with embedded newlines:

```
>>> r = console.push('def test2(n):\n  return n+10\n')
>>> r = console.push('test2(10)')
20
>>>

# the following, however, fails...
>>> r = console.push('test(10)\ntest(15)')
  File "<console>", line 1
    test(10)
           ^
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think so. That class only adds input buffering and prompts. There's nothing in the docs about automatic evaluation.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but I've updated my comment with a code example of what I *think* you are asking for.

Comment: The `InteractiveConsole.push` method fails for the same reason as `InteractiveInterpreter.runsource`; it doesn't accept more than one statement as input. +1 for the useful info though.

Comment: I just added an example of how multiple statements are added. The return value (which I capture in `r`) is helpful when adding multiple statements. See the docs linked.

Comment: So, you're suggesting splitting input on new lines, and push each one separately? I'm worried this will cause problems for my application, each input runs in it's own thread, so there'd probably be race conditions. I'll still mark this as correct, it is the right answer to the question. I don't expect you to handle my threads too :)

Comment: Also (sometimes) works with embedded newlines. But execution kills it. Example added.